# How to guarantee Kivy root widget properties will be referenced only after initialization?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I recently followed the [Kivy pong game tutorial](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/tutorials/pong.html) and decided to go a little further and have the game ball start at the same speed each round, but slowly increase in speed as the round progresses. I added code (to `PongGame.p1_start()` and `PongGame.p2_start()`) that set the initial speed of the ball each round based on the width of the root widget.

The problem is that the starting speed of the ball for the first round is slower than the initial speed of the ball for all subsequent rounds. For some reason, the speed of the ball the first round is set before the root widget is fully initialized, so the default widget width of 100 is used instead of the widget's true width once it's been initialized.

Here's the function where the ball speed is set:

```py
    def p1_start(self, *args):
        self.ball.direction_x = -1.0
        self.ball.direction_y = 0.0
        self.ball.speed = 0.05*self.width
```

I could work out a crude workaround, but it wouldn't be pretty. Is there a clean way to get around this issue?

Comment: Try calling that method using `Clock.schedule_once()`.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick! And just the fix I was looking for: elegant and simple. Thanks!